# In C#, what's the difference of PrinterSettings from a PrintDocument and PrintDialog?

Tags: c#, driver, printers

Well, it's a very strange problem, and I already found a black magical solution. I'm curious about the reason.

I'm writing a program which use Brother QL-700 label printer to print labels. I need the labels be printed without showing the printer dialog. 
The label printer support different size of label rolls and the default size of label roll is 29mm, while what I need is 62mm. I found that I can set the Page Size by

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
PaperSize size = new PaperSize() ;
size.Width = 244;//2.44 inch = 62mm
size.Height = 244;
size.RawKind = 256;//RawKind=0 does not work, I don't know why
doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;
```

However, this won't work, the driver of Printer would show a message saying the width does not fit.

But if I change the copy the PrinterSettings from a `PrintDialog()`, without showing it,

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

doc.PrinterSettings = dlg.PrinterSettings;
```

Then it works.

In conclusion, what I don't understand is why

```
size.RawKind = 256;
```

and

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
doc.PrinterSettings = dlg.PrinterSettings;
```

can make the printer work?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [RawKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not state that 0 is a valid value.  It also states that any value above 118 indicates a custom paper size.  Since you are specifying a custom paper size, the value of 256 indicates that the size is custom and that is why it works.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know anything about the difference between the default PrinterSettings of PrintDialog and PrintDocument?